# Bulid recursive function run on stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

I want to build item tree with recursive function...(`<ul><li>`)
someone can help me with this? how can i run on this array? for example...

I use Codeigniter If it changes anything....

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1000
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1001
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1002
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1003
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1004
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Output needs to be like this:

```
<div class="dd">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1000">
            <div class="dd-handle">parent 1000</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="1001">
                    <div class="dd-handle">children of 1000 and parent of 1002</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1002">
                            <div class="dd-handle">children of 1001</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1003">
            <div class="dd-handle">parent 1003</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="1004">
                    <div class="dd-handle">children of 1003</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: [Where are you stuck?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How can i build the recursive function \=

Comment: What exactly do you want it turned into - give us some sample output.

Comment: The output need to look like <ul></li> list...

Comment: That could be interpreted in several ways - add some HTML to your question.

Comment: ן addes the html output example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function render(array $children) {
    echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
    foreach($children as $child) {
        echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="', $child->id, '">';
        echo '<div class="dd-handle">parent ', $child->id, '</div>';
        if(isset($child->children)) {
            render($child->children);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

echo '<div class="dd">';
render($array);
echo '</div>';
```